# What is wrong with my lisp function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am writing a function called palindrome that tests if a list is a palindrome. It works 100% for regular lists such as (1 2 1), but if I use (1 (2) 1), I get a bad argument type error.

Here is my function

```
(defun palindrome (x)                      
   (if (NULL x) t                           
   (let ( ( a (car x)) (b (lastelement x)))  
      (if ( = a b)                           
        (palindrome (cdr (butlast x)))       
      nil))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `=` is reserved exclusively for numbers. When used with a list or other type of element it returns an error. Use instead `eql`.

Incidentally, note that your function is very inefficient. Normally (i.e. not for homework) you would create a reversed copy of the list and compare it element by element with the original list.

Comment: Thank you very much. You caught me red handed as this is a homework question XD, and my instructor told us to not use reverse.

Comment: I am very new to lisp, and I completely forgot about the difference between the = and eq operator. Thank you!